# Send a reminder email when post has expired

Tags: php, email, wordpress

I am using some code i found online to hide a post when an expiration date is set in a custom meta box. I am able to accomplish this just fine, but now i would like to create a function that scans all of my posts and if anyone of them has a date in the past i would like to trigger a reminder email that goes out to an email address i designate using custom fields.

Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated:

```
//Sends Expirary Email
function plugin_email_reminder() {
    global $post;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'coupon',
        'p'         => $post_id
    );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 

    //Sets Expiration
    $expirationtime = get_post_custom_values('coupon_expiration');
        if (is_array($expirationtime)) {
        $expirestring = implode($expirationtime);
    }
    $secondsbetween = strtotime($expirestring)-time();
        if ( $secondsbetween <= 0 ) {

    // Start the code to send the emails
    $to = get_option('plugin_email_address');
    $subject = get_the_title(). ' Post has expired';
    $headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo('name').' <no-reply@nomail.com>';
    $message = get_the_title(). ' Post has expired. If you would like it to appear please change the expiration date.';
    wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
    // End the code to send the emails          

    }           

    endforeach; 
}
```

I can get the email to trigger when just put the code below in my single.php loop

```
    $expirationtime = get_post_custom_values('coupon_expiration');
        if (is_array($expirationtime)) {
        $expirestring = implode($expirationtime);
    }
    $secondsbetween = strtotime($expirestring)-time();
        if ( $secondsbetween <= 0 ) {

    // Start the code to send the emails
    $to = get_option('plugin_email_address');
    $subject = get_the_title(). ' Post has expired';
    $headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo('name').' <no-reply@nomail.com>';
    $message = get_the_title(). ' Post has expired. If you would like it to appear please change the expiration date.';
    wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
    // End the code to send the emails          

    }
```

But the email goes out only if i go to that single.php page on my website. I would like this reminder email to be dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you need a scheduler to run this script at specified times - checkout the answers to this post and pick one that fits http://stackoverflow.com/q/190561/1370442

Comment: Separate the process of periodically scanning the data from the website itself and schedule it with a `cron` job.  Websites aren't very good at performing regularly scheduled tasks.

Comment: Create a CRON job that runs at 2 AM in the morning or something like that everyday and checks whether the thing has expired or not. This script only runs when you visit the page (otherwise its not executed, for obvious reasons). CRON jobs automatically run your scripts at a specified time (which can be days/hours/mins/whatever).

Comment: @bUKaneer No, don't do that. [WordPress has a built-in scheduler.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)